# How to reduce billing on my AWS RDS instance

Tags: amazon-rds

We currently pay somewhere between 85-100 USD on a monthly basis for RDS usage. But most of the times we don't access our database instances. Is there a way to reduce the billing by bringing down the instance or go in for a shared database mode. What kind of alternatives exist?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it pertains to the billing practices of a particular service provider, and not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete an instance at any time with [DeleteDBInstance](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteDBInstance.html).  By default, a final snapshot will be created .  Then, you can recreate it at a later time.  See [this FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#27).  The final snapshot storage cost is $0.15 per GB-month.

Answer (score 3):

Even I was facing this issue. With AWS; RDS is much more expensive than EC2 instances. And database is something which needs to run for 24*7 in my case as compared to EC2 instances which can be optimized.

The way I opted for reducing my costs for RDS is go for "Reserved Instance" .. Anyway RDS is something which I will always need ( until I am on AWS ). This way I could reduce my costs by around 50%.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options you can leverage to reduce RDS costs. You mention that you are not using your RDS instance most of the time, so that is the first obvious place to look for savings:

1. If you only use the instance for, say, 8 hours/day, 09:00 - 17:00, set up a scheduled job to shut down the instance at 17:00 and start it back up at 09:00.
2. Look at serverless RDS instances. They shut down after an idle period. You should be aware, however, that if you have monitoring hooked into your RDS instance, the monitoring will create enough workload to prevent the instance from ever going to sleep, so it is only suitable for a very narrow range of uses and needs to be considered very carefully.
3. As mentioned elsewhere in the thread, switch to an EC2 instance and manage your own database. That will save you approximately half in costs compared to a similarly specced RDS instance.

Answer (score 1):

AWS added the ability to [shut down](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-rds-supports-stopping-and-starting-of-database-instances/) (but not delete!) RDS instances when you are not using them. That way, you only pay for the data storage, which is much cheaper than the actual running DB. You can use the [AWS Instance Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/infrastructure-management/instance-scheduler/) to automatically shut down RDS DBs and EC2 Instances on a scheduled basis, such as at night and on weekends in non-production environments.

You can find more info on this, plus other AWS cost optimization tips in the [AWS Production Readiness Checklist](https://gruntwork.io/devops-checklist/).